# Access JSON data using a value from localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, phaser-framework

After searching online and not finding anything, I decided to post here.

What I have so far:

- JSON

I have a JSON file, with several list of words that I need to retrieve according to user input. They look something like this:

```
{
    "length": 10,
    "targetWords": {
        "SOME_NAME": [
            {
                "words": [
               "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz",
                "xyz"
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "Some example text",
                "letter": "X",
            }
        ],
}
```

- localStorage input

I ask the user to choose an option and "record" that answer in a variable. Let's call it "userInput".

```
userInput = localStorage.getItem("something")
```

- I get the JSON and pass it to a variable (I'm using Phaser Framework)

`TARGET_SOUNDS_DATA = this.game.cache.getJSON('targetSounds')`

What I want now is to access the values inside it. I can do it if I go about it like this:

```
TARGET_SOUNDS_WORDS_ARRAY = TARGET_SOUNDS_DATA.targetWords.SOME_NAME[0].words
```

But unable to do so if I use the user answer/input like this:

```
TARGET_SOUNDS_WORDS_ARRAY =TARGET_SOUNDS_DATA.targetWords.userInput[0].words
```

This way I only get *undefined*

So I know I'm doing something wrong but what?

Any help/hints are welcomed! Thanks for your time!

Cheers,
J

Comment: you must save your json in localStorage with JSON.stringify(YOUR_DATA), to parse to string, and then recover it with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("something"))`

Comment: @Tushar, yes I know. What I want is NOT store objects using localStorage. Is to retrieve data from A JSON file using input from an user stored as a localStorage key/value and used as variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse it and then to get result based on userInput access it like this

```
TARGET_SOUNDS_WORDS_ARRAY =TARGET_SOUNDS_DATA.targetWords[userInput][0].words
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use square brackets to select a property with a variable

```
TARGET_SOUNDS_WORDS_ARRAY = TARGET_SOUNDS_DATA.targetWords[userInput][0].words
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, and maybe I'm wrong, localStorage is key/value storage only. You'll have to convert the json to a string, store it, then retrieve it and convert it back to an object when you want to use it.

Comment: Hi dgig! You're right, localStorage is key/value only. Using the getJSON() method you (my turn to say -> as far as I know)  get the data as an object!